# Use of ngsanitize with css

Tags: angularjs, .net-core, ngsanitize

[image]

While using ngsanitize. It displays only html without css applied.

For example:
The above image should be the output but using ngsanitize ,it displays only the text

What could be added with ngsanitize to display elements with proper css.

```
<p ng-bind-html ="the text to be displayed(test video)"></p>
```

Comment: Please add an example of the code you use, it will help us understand the question better.

Answer (score 1):

if i understood your question correctly, [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k6pyjbwt/3/)

you can use $sce.trustAsHtml(), to use inline style directly into the html string, you could do it like this, controller:

```
$scope.trustAsHtml = function(string) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(string);
};
```

And in HTML

```
<div data-ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(htmlString)"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with `$sce`. Before binding it to the scope variable that you use for `ng-bind-html`. An example below

```
<p ng-bind-html ="styledHTML"></p>
```

And in your controller

```
$scope.styledHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml('<span style="background-color: cyan;">test video</span>');
```